# Metadata per frame for VP9

Tags: video, metadata, matroska, vp9

I have a stream of images which I would be encoding in VP9 and storing in a container like matroska (mkv). Each image in the stream has a metadata associated with it which we can assume as an array of bytes. What is a good way of associating this metadata per frame in the final video file?

1. Is it possible to store this metadata as part of vp9 encoded video stream?
2. Should I make use of subtitle stream of mkv container as my metadata stream?